# Bibtex add space in a citation with more than one item

Tags: bibtex

I am writing an article using the `iopart` class for LaTeX. This format is not compatible with BibLaTeX so I am forced to use BibTeX for referencing.

I want to put more than two entries in the same citation but when doing that the spacing comes out weirdly. Here is an example:

I put this in the `.bib` file (called `bibexample`),

```
@article{example1,
title={{Example 1}},
author={me},
eprint={123}
} 

@article{example2,
title={{Example 2}},
author={me again},
eprint={456}
}
```

and in the document

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mcite}


\begin{document}
Here is my example as seen in \cite{example1, *example2}
\section*{References}

\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}
\bibliography{bibexample}

\end{document}
```

The final result is:

[image]

As you can see, there is no space between `123` and `me again`. I would like to solve this in a proper way. I have seen that if I change `title={{Example 2}}` to `title={{ Example 2}}` my issue is solved but I would like to know if there is a proper way of fixing this.

The necessary files for using the `iopart` document class can be found here: https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/questions/latex-template/

The package for using the `iopart-num` bibliography style is on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/iopart-num

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which versions are you using? I get a line break after the 123

Comment: @daleif which versions of what exactly?

Comment: Your latex installation plus versions for hyperref and mcite. You can add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` then all the file versions are printed to the log and you can update your question with this information.

Comment: I can see that both iopart.cls and mcite seems to be from 1996!! plus I have a hyperref from 2020.

Comment: My latex version is from 2017 and my hyperref is from 2016... You suggest that actualising these two would solve the issue?

Comment: No idea, just that I do not the the image you you present using newer larex. I'm just wondering why that class has not been updated since 1996 if it is still being used to submit articles.

Comment: I will try upgrading to the new versions. I am also wondering why the class has not been updated and why it is incompatible with amsmath being a scientific journal...

Comment: They might have updated it but never bothered to change the date. But that is probably unlikely. Not that mcite is also from the same period